# paramiko channel auto-complete not working

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, autocomplete, paramiko

I download this webshell demo code from internet, its auto-complete(pass '\t\t') works well

```
import paramiko
import threading
import sys
import readchar

class SSHClient:
    def __init__(self, hostname, port, username, password):
        self.client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        self.client.connect(hostname, port, username, password)
        self.channel = self.client.invoke_shell()
        self.input_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.send_input)
        self.output_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.receive_output)
        self.is_running = True

    def send_input(self):
        while self.is_running:
            char = readchar.readchar()
            self.channel.send(char)

    def receive_output(self):
        while self.is_running:
            if self.channel.recv_ready():
                output = self.channel.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                sys.stdout.write(output)
                sys.stdout.flush()

    def start(self):
        self.input_thread.start()
        self.output_thread.start()
        self.input_thread.join()
        self.output_thread.join()

    def close(self):
        self.channel.close()
        self.client.close()

hostname = '127.0.0.1'
port = 2222
username = 'zed'
password = '123456'

client = SSHClient(hostname, port, username, password)
client.start()
```

base on demo above, I implement my webshell for my home's IoT gateway, but its auto-complete not working

```
from time import time, sleep
from hashlib import sha256
from string import ascii_letters, digits
from random import choice
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json
import signal
import paramiko
import websocket
import threading
import queue
from datetime import datetime
from socket import error as socket_error
import os
import yaml

# 设备三元组
device_product_key = ''
device_name = ''
device_secret = ''

# mqtt
broker_host = ''
broker_port = 1883

# SSH_REQUEST_IDENTIFIER
ssh_request_identifier = ''

# websocket 配置
ws_host = ''
max_ws_size = 1024 * 4

# sshd 连接信息
host = ''
port = 2222
username = ''
password = ''

class ws_heartbeat_thread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ws):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ws = ws
    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                self.ws.send("<heartbeat>")
                sleep(20)
            except websocket.WebSocketConnectionClosedException:
                print("WebSocket connection closed")
                break

class ws_listen_ssh_resp_thread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ws, channel):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ws = ws
        self.channel = channel
    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.channel.recv_ready():
                chunk = self.channel.recv(max_ws_size).decode('utf-8')
                self.ws.send(chunk)
                continue
            if self.channel.exit_status_ready():
                break
            if self.channel.closed or self.channel.eof_received or not self.channel.active:
                break

def ws_conn(token, ssh_client):

    def ws_on_open(ws):
        print(token + " WebSocket connected")
        heartbeat_thread.start()
        ssh_resp_thread.start()

    def ws_on_message(ws, message):
        print(token + " recv ws msg:", message)
        if message == "<heartbeat>":
            # channel.send('\t\t')
            return
        channel.send(message)
        
    def ws_on_close(ws, close_code, close_reason):
        heartbeat_thread.join()
        ssh_resp_thread.join()
        print(token + " websocket closed")

    def ws_on_error(ws, err):
        print("error encountered:", err)
        channel.send(err)
        ws.close()

    url = f"wss://{ws_host}/iot/webshell?webShellToken={token}&source=device"
    # 创建 WebSocket 客户端实例
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(url,
                                on_open=ws_on_open,
                                on_message=ws_on_message,
                                on_close=ws_on_close,
                                on_error=ws_on_error,
                                keep_running=True)

    ssh_client.connect(host, port, username, password)
    # channel = ssh_client.get_transport().open_session()
    # channel.get_pty()
    # channel.invoke_shell()
    channel = ssh_client.invoke_shell()
    
    channel.send("stty -echo\n")
    ssh_resp_thread = ws_listen_ssh_resp_thread(ws, channel)
    heartbeat_thread = ws_heartbeat_thread(ws)
    sleep(0.5)
    # 运行 WebSocket 客户端
    ws.run_forever()
    


def get_mqtt_info(product_key, device_name, app_secret, timestamp):
    user_name = f"{product_key}&{device_name}"
    encode_str = f"={device_name}&{product_key}&{app_secret}&{timestamp}&"
    print(f"encode_str= {encode_str}")
    signature = sha256(encode_str.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()[5:15].lower()
    password = f"{timestamp}&{signature}"
    letters = ascii_letters + digits  # 包含字母和数字的字符
    client_id = ''.join(choice(letters) for _ in range(8))
    return {"client_id": client_id, "user_name": user_name, "password": password}


def on_rpc_request(client, userdata, msg):
    print(f'{datetime.now()} get request {msg.payload.decode()}')
    req_payload = json.loads(msg.payload.decode())
    print(f'get request {req_payload}')
    body = req_payload['body']
    req_id, cmd_id, body_id = req_payload['id'], body['params']['commandID'], body['identifier']
    if ssh_request_identifier != body_id:
        return
    resp_topic = f'$system/{device_product_key}/{device_name}/server/rpc/response'
    resp_body = {
        "id": req_id,
        "body": {
            "identifier": body_id,
            "params": {
                "commandID": cmd_id,
                "time": '%d' % int(time() * 1000),
                "msg": "success",
                "code": 200
            }
        }
    }

    token = body['params']['token']
    ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    # 自动添加远程主机的 SSH 公钥
    ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    print(f"connect ssh")
    # 连接远程服务器
    try:
        ws_thread = threading.Thread(target=ws_conn, args=(token, ssh_client))
        ws_thread.start()
    except (paramiko.BadHostKeyException, paramiko.AuthenticationException):
        resp_body['body']['params']['msg'] = "failed to auth ssh"
        resp_body['body']['params']['code'] = 403
    except (socket_error, paramiko.SSHException):
        resp_body['body']['params']['msg'] = "connection error"
        resp_body['body']['params']['code'] = 404
    except:
        resp_body['body']['params']['msg'] = "error unknown"
        resp_body['body']['params']['code'] = 404
    resp_str = json.dumps(resp_body)
    print(f"{datetime.now()} publish {resp_str}")
    client.publish(resp_topic, resp_str)


# 定义回调函数
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc == 0:
        print("MQTT Broker Connected")
        # 订阅主题
        topic = f'$system/{device_product_key}/{device_name}/server/rpc/request'
        client.subscribe(topic, 0, on_message)
    else:
        print("Failed to connect MQTT Broker")


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print("收到消息: " + msg.topic + " " + str(msg.payload))
    if msg.topic == f'$system/{device_product_key}/{device_name}/server/rpc/request':
        on_rpc_request(client, userdata, msg)


def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    current_pid = os.getpid()
    os.kill(current_pid, signal.SIGKILL)
    print("已断开连接")

def init_config():
    with open('conf.yaml', 'r') as file:
        config = yaml.safe_load(file)

    # 设备三元组
    global device_product_key
    device_product_key = config['device-info']['product_key']
    global device_name
    device_name = config['device-info']['device_name']
    global device_secret
    device_secret = config['device-info']['device_secret']

    # mqtt
    global broker_host
    broker_host = config['mqtt']['broker_host']
    global broker_port
    broker_port = config['mqtt']['broker_port']

    # SSH_REQUEST_IDENTIFIER
    global ssh_request_identifier
    ssh_request_identifier = config['mqtt']['ssh_request_identifier']

    # websocket 配置
    global ws_host
    ws_host = config['websocket-broker']['host']
    global max_ws_size
    max_ws_size = config['websocket-broker']['max-size']

    # sshd 连接信息
    global host
    host = config['sshd']['host']
    global port
    port = config['sshd']['port']
    global username
    username = config['sshd']['username']
    global password
    password = config['sshd']['password']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init_config()
    mqtt_params = get_mqtt_info(device_product_key, device_name, device_secret, int(time()) * 1000)

    print(mqtt_params)
    # 创建MQTT客户端
    mq_client = mqtt.Client(client_id=mqtt_params['client_id'])


    def signal_handler(sig, frame):
        mq_client.disconnect()
        mq_client.loop_stop()


    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

    # 设置回调函数
    mq_client.on_connect = on_connect
    mq_client.on_message = on_message
    mq_client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect

    mq_client.username_pw_set(mqtt_params['user_name'], mqtt_params['password'])

    # 连接到MQTT Broker
    mq_client.connect(broker_host, broker_port, 60)

    # 保持连接
    mq_client.loop_forever()
    print(f"finished!")
```

I think the ssh part is completely same, and both of them connect to the same ssh server when I test them.

address reasons why second code snippet cant use auto-complete

Comment: I addressed the problem. the client of second code sippet did not sent '\x1b[{$LINIE_NUMBER};{$COLUMN_NUMBER}R' to ssh channel after received prompt